# Can Restlet be used as a client of a Rails "rest" api?

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, restlet

I'm used to work with Restkit in iOS. With restkit I'm able to do restful stuff on iOS with a rails server. (Yes, rails is not the best for rest, but with a bit of tweaking, you can make it behave like a rest server).

Now I'm looking for something similar to Restkit but for Android. Will Restlet be able to do the job?

If so, could you point to any tutorial? Is hard to find a tutorial for Restlet-Android-Rails

```
#n00b
```

**What I've tried so far**

***On my main activity creation:***

```
Engine.getInstance().getRegisteredConverters().add(new JacksonConverter());
ClientResource cr = new ClientResource("http://localhost:5000/api/feedback/30");
cr.setRequestEntityBuffering(true);
cr.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
FeedbackResource resource = cr.wrap(FeedbackResource.class);
Feedback feedback = resource.retrieve();
System.out.println(feedback);
```

***My FeedbackResource.java resource***

```
package com.blablabla.backendResources;

import com.blablabla.model.Feedback;
import org.restlet.resource.Delete;
import org.restlet.resource.Get;
import org.restlet.resource.Put;

public interface FeedbackResource
{
    @Get("json")
    public Feedback retrieve();

    @Put("json")
    public void store(Feedback feedback);

    @Delete
    public void remove();
}
```

***Feedback.java***

```
package com.blablabla.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Feedback implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String comment;

    public Feedback() {
        super();
    }

    public Feedback(int id, String name, String email, String comment) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.comment = comment;
    }

    public int getId()
    {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(int id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getComment() {
        return comment;
    }

    public void setComment(String comment) {
        this.comment = comment;
    }
}
```

**ALL THAT FAILS :(, but with curl:**

```
curl -X GET -H "Accept:application/json"  http://localhost:5000/api/feedback/30
```

Response:

{"id":30,"name":"","email":"","comment":"Opino popo"}

**As suggested by @Caleryn, I went to basics and just tried to do a get, but even on that I failed:**

***Error:***

> 05-21 10:08:36.762      669-669/com.reserbus W/System.err﹕ Starting
>   the internal HTTP client 05-21 10:08:36.802      669-669/com.reserbus
>   W/System.err﹕ A recoverable error was detected (1000), attempting
>   again in 2000 ms. 05-21 10:08:38.822      669-669/com.reserbus
>   W/System.err﹕ A recoverable error was detected (1000), attempting
>   again in 2000 ms. 05-21 10:08:40.842      669-669/com.reserbus
>   W/System.err﹕ Connection Error (1000) - The connector failed to
>   connect to the server 05-21 10:08:40.852      669-669/com.reserbus
>   W/System.err﹕ at
>   org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.doError(ClientResource.java:599)
>   05-21 10:08:40.852      669-669/com.reserbus W/System.err﹕ at
>   org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handleInbound(ClientResource.java:1165)
>   05-21 10:08:40.852      669-669/com.reserbus W/System.err﹕ at
>   org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:1060)
>   05-21 10:08:40.852      669-669/com.reserbus W/System.err﹕ at
>   org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:1077)
>   05-21 10:08:40.852      669-669/com.reserbus W/System.err﹕ at
>   org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:969)
>   05-21 10:08:40.862      669-669/com.reserbus W/System.err﹕ at
>   org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.get(ClientResource.java:687) 05-21
>   10:08:40.862      669-669/com.reserbus W/System.err﹕ at
>   com.reserbus.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:50)

***Code***

```
try {
  System.out.println(new ClientResource("http://localhost:5000/api/feedback/30.json").get(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).getText());
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Why don't you try via a simple test?

Comment: I'm trying and failing. Let me show the code on an edit.

Comment: What does `System.out.println(new ClientResource("http://localhost:5000/api/feedback/30").get(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).getText());` get you?  You will probably want to expand that one line out. But it should get you the raw response and hopefully reduce the problem a little.

Comment: @Caleryn That was a good idea, however even on that I'm failing. I'll put the error on an edit.

Comment: @LayGonzález well that does narrow it down, to problems connecting and not parsing, you will need to have a look at how the server side (rails) is handling those packets. Also check for firewall interference. I am also intrigued that you are specifying a file extension on the restlet version but not the curl? Have you tried without that, in the url? You may need to get Wireshark (or similar) out.

Comment: @Caleryn, sorry for not documenting; I tried with and without the json extension.  (rails handles that as if the accept type is json). I will pay closer attention to network problems as you suggest. Thanks.

Comment: The stacktrace shows that the client can't connect to the server. As the server respond, I suspect the issue is in the Android application.
Did you provide the INTERNET permission to your Android application?